# Using CDN together with SSL

Tags: ssl, https, cdn

My website is in HTTPS, and I am trying out CloudFlare as CDN. In CloudFlare there is a SSL option. Should I enable it or not? If I enable it, then which SSL cert will the user's browser load? (the original SSL cert vs CloudFlare SSL cert) Or do I need to turn off SSL in my original server, and only turn on SSL in the CDN?

I am trying to find an article explaining the SSL mechanism when using CDN, but seems not much articles are talking about. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution - just set "Full" SSL method in CloudFlare, so that both the host & CloudFlare have SSL cert and able to connect to each other securely